# How to change Gallery image url in product page ? In function.php?

Tags: images, filters, post-thumbnails, gallery

My code is like

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url', function($url){
    if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'image/webp')!=false){
        return $url.".webp";
    }else{
        return $url;
    }
});
```

But only the last image in Gallery changed to xxx.webp . I want to know how to change other image ....I want all of them changed to xxx.webp

I dont want use a plugin (Or if i have to ...),Please HELP ,Thanks .

Comment: First make sure that you have a .webp image. Your code always appends .webp but you first need to remove the image suffix, a .jpg image becomes .jpg.webp image with your current code.

Comment: Of course .webp is existed.And image url is like a.jpg.webp. It's correct.I just want to know  how to change other image url.

Comment: Wordpress doesn't come with gallery, so im guessing theres a plugin you use for displaying gallery, what is the plugin? btw this might get your question closed because plugins are considered off-topic

Comment: Just WooCommerce .Product page .Theme is Flatsome.

Comment: After looking in the woocommerce github repo i found this filter `woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html`, this filter is responsible for the html structure of the image, start with this

Comment: Thank you !That's what i need.The best answer ! O(∩_∩)O